# Cancel alarmmanager from broadcast receiver using Pending intent

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-pendingintent

I have created a BroadCastReceiver which schedules some events using alarm manager.

In the BroadcastReceiver I am using following code to schedule.

```
Intent localIntent = new Intent("com.test.sample");

        PendingIntent  pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,
                    localIntent, 0);
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP,
                    SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + (5 * 60 * 1000),
                    pi);
```

Here **context** comes from the onReceive method of the receiver.

I want to cancel this alarm on receive of other broadcast. 
I am aware that alarm can be cancelled by  `alarmManager.cancel(pi);`

**However if the alarmanager was set from any other activity that how to get hold of PendingIntent to cancel it?**

Thanks

Comment: just create a new PendingIntent

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to create a new `PendingIntent` with the same `id` then pass it as argument in `cancelAlarm()` method like follows:

To create alarm

```
int alarmId = 0; /* Dynamically assign alarm ids for multiple alarms */
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class); /* your Intent localIntent = new Intent("com.test.sample");*/
intent.putExtra("alarmId", alarmId); /* So we can catch the id on BroadcastReceiver */
PendingIntent alarmIntent;
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,
        alarmId, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

To cancel alarm (in `BroadcastReceiver`whitin `onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)`method)

```
int alarmId = intent.getExtras().getInt("alarmId");
PendingIntent alarmIntent;
alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, alarmId, 
        new Intent(this, AlarmReceiver.class),
        PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
cancelAlarm(alarmIntent);
```

Comment: it's not mandatory to specify FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT, you could pass 0 as flag

Comment: What if I don´t have the id?